# Where does this $resource variable come from?

Tags: angularjs

The [angular documentation for `$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) has the following example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

I've been googling and reading documenation and can't figure out how `@id` is being populated.  There's not a section within `$resources` that appears to explain this.  It must be something somewhere else in the documentation that I haven't encountered.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET operations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the url `/user/:userId`, the `userId` part is a placeholder. You're telling AngularJS to replace that with the actual user id to get the real url.

In the second part, where you write `{userId : '@id'}`, you are telling AngularJS, that if a `userId` is not specified, it should use the `id` property from the object.

I'll try to illustrate with a few examples:

If you do

```
var user = User.get({userId : 123});
```

You have explicitly specified a value for `userId` so Angular will use that to create the url `/user/123/`. However, if you do

```
var user = User();
user.id = 123;
user.get()
```

In this case, you did not explicitly specify a value of `userId`, so Angular will use the value of `user.id` for `userId`, and again create the url `/user/123/`.

Like rajkamal mentions, this is useful for non-GET operations. A real use case is where you do something like this:

```
// user wants to work with Post 10. So we fetch that
var post = Post.get({postId : 10});

// user works with it, makes some changes
post.body = 'New body';
post.topic = 'New topic';

// user is done, and wants to save. You make a POST call
// without having to specify it's id again
post.save();
```

Comment: So if I'm using Services as shown here: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/services.js how would I send a parameter to the service method?

Comment: You can pass it as as second argument, exactly how I'm fetching a post in the example I put above. When you're fetching a Phone / Post, you will know what the id of the object is, so you pass it in as an argument. For subsequent non-GET calls, you don't need to pass it in.